# I need question mark in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

please help me. I need correct RewriteRule. I have search form with GET method, but when i use submit button so nothing is do.

**My bad RewireRule:**

```
RewriteRule inzercia/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?f_keyword=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&f_cena_od=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&f_cena_do=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&f_psc=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&f_kraj=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&f_typy=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&f_hladat=$ inzercia.php?cat_seo=$1&subcat_seo=$2&f_keyword=$3&f_cena_od=$4&f_cena_do=$5&f_psc=$6&f_kraj=$7&f_typy=$8&f_hladat=
```

**My Url:**

```
http://domain.com/inzercia/stavebny-material/elektroinstalacny-material?f_keyword=&f_cena_od=&f_cena_do=&f_psc=&f_kraj=&f_typy=&f_hladat=
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string inside a rewrite rule, you need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^f_keyword=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&f_cena_od=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&f_cena_do=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&f_psc=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&f_kraj=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&f_typy=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&f_hladat=$
RewriteRule inzercia/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) inzercia.php?cat_seo=$1&subcat_seo=$2&f_keyword=%1&f_cena_od=%2&f_cena_do=%3&f_psc=%4&f_kraj=%5&f_typy=%6&f_hladat= [L]
```

However, since you aren't changing the query string at all, you could just try:

```
RewriteRule inzercia/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) inzercia.php?cat_seo=$1&subcat_seo=$2 [L,QSA]
```

utilizing the `QSA` flag to append any existing query string to the end of the target.